# Como puedo cambiar el efecto de transicion del carrusel de bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, carrusel, slide

Quiero cambiar el efecto de slide de bootsrap que trae por defecto, en ves de que el slide pase a la izquierda me gustaria que este se difumine lentamente y cambie por el siguiente slide. Es bootstrap V4.

```css
* {
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 15rem auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.titempl {
    width: 22rem;
    height: 5.2rem;
    background-color: #1A455D;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 2rem 0rem 2rem 0rem;
    margin-left: 6rem;
}

.TextoTamaño {
    text-align: center;
}

.titempl {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 34px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
}

.cuadro {
    background-color: #999;
    width: 30rem;
    height: 22.5rem;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
}

.logo {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.botones {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}

.boton {
    display: flex;
    align-items: end;
    justify-content: end;
    background-color: #1A455D;
    color: #ffff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.boton:hover {
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #1A455D;
    color: #7FA439;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="misionvision.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="carrusel">
            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col ">
                                <div class="cuadro ">
                                    <img src="vision.png " alt="First slide " width="360rem " height="360rem ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col ">
                                <h1 class="titempl ">
                                    <div class="TextoTamaño "><img class="img-fluid " src="hv.png ">Misión</div>
                                </h1>
                                <br><br>
                                <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem et laudantium illo voluptatum architecto modi nemo sit suscipit. Veniam alias, voluptate voluptatibus magnam sed sint modi perferendis asperiores animi
                                    quos!
                                </h2>
                                <div class="logo ">
                                    <img class="img-fluid " src="hv.png ">Interclean
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item ">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col ">
                                <div class="cuadro ">
                                    <img src="vision.png " alt="First slide " width="360rem " height="360rem ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col ">
                                <h1 class="titempl ">
                                    <div class="TextoTamaño "><img class="img-fluid " src="hv.png ">Visión</div>
                                </h1>
                                <br><br>
                                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam soluta labore, qui voluptatem maiores debitis ex, ipsam nesciunt, consequuntur veritatis explicabo natus iste ullam eligendi incidunt eaque quae ipsa illo.</h2>
                                <div class="logo ">
                                    <img class="img-fluid " src="hv.png ">Interclean
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item ">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col ">
                                <div class="cuadro ">
                                    <img src="vision.png " alt="First slide " width="360rem " height="360rem ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col ">
                                <h1 class="titempl ">
                                    <div class="TextoTamaño "><img class="img-fluid " src="hv.png ">Pendiente nombre
                                    </div>
                                </h1>
                                <br><br>
                                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam soluta labore, qui voluptatem maiores debitis ex, ipsam nesciunt, consequuntur veritatis explicabo natus iste ullam eligendi incidunt eaque quae ipsa illo.</h2>
                                <div class="logo ">
                                    <img class="img-fluid " src="hv.png ">Interclean
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="botones ">
                    <button class="boton " href="#carouselExampleControls " role="button " data-slide="prev ">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon " aria-hidden="true "></span>
                        <span class="sr-only ">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="boton " href="#carouselExampleControls " role="button " data-slide="next ">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon " aria-hidden="true "></span>
                        <span class="sr-only ">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js " integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Para que te ayudemos mejor, por lo menos agrega tu HTML5, y la versión de tu bootstrap, para ver qué intentaste.

Comment: listo, copie y pegue el problema porque me salia algo de que era más código. Aún soy novato.

Comment: Lastimosamente bootstrap 4.0 no tiene ese estilo de transición. Pero si está disponible desde la versión 4.5. si podés descargar y aplicar la versión 4.5 de bootstrap, estaría genial

Comment: Para que te informes más, fíjate este enlace: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/

Comment: Me funciono, muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

te recommendaria que si no te quieres hacer mucho lio  con Boostrap busques un snippet de algun slider que tenga el efecto que quieres pero en CSS puro, seria un poco obsoleto utilizar Js para crear un slider tan simple. Saludos!

Comment: En realidad, el efecto que busca el OP lo hace Bootstrap con CSS y la clase `.carousel-fade`. Para el carousel, JS se utiliza para el comportamiento de las diapositivas, como los indicadores de control. Revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Al fin y al cabo el elemento terminado acaba conteniendo JavaScript, puede utilizar un slider CSS que si no lo sabe escribir puede recurrir a Codepen por ej, y el comportamiento del pase de diapositivas, los controladores y todo lo demas se escribe en css...